# Problem While Connecting Two Classes(or Projects) in java

Tags: java

So here's the thing i have two projects and wanna connect both of them. I'm able to connect them. But when i open the first project and press the button that is linked to the other project, it does open the other project but the other project simply shows a blank screen and doesn't work. I've tried running the project directly and it is working but when i do the same through another project it doesn't work for some reason.

Now, I don't just want answers but also possible extensions and upgrades i can do to advance my project further. Moreover to tell ya' this is a game i am making ;D. Please reply. Here is my first code for the project with the linking button-:`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class gameteststart implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1;
    JLabel title;
    JButton b1;

    gameteststart() {
        f1 = new JFrame("Game");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        title = new JLabel("Scratchophobia");
        b1 = new JButton("Play");
        Font fnt = new Font("", Font.BOLD, 18);
        Font fnt1 = new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 11);

        p1.setLayout(null);

        f1.add(p1);
        p1.add(title);
        p1.add(b1);

        title.setBounds(230, 75, 200, 100);
        b1.setBounds(250, 245, 100, 25);

        f1.setSize(600, 500);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        p1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        title.setBackground(Color.RED);
        b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        b1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f1.setResizable(false);

        title.setFont(fnt);
        b1.setFont(fnt1);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            gametest obj = new gametest();
            f1.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Game-Started");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        gameteststart obj = new gameteststart();
    }
}
```

And here's the second code:

```
//keylisteners

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;

class gametest implements KeyListener {
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1;
    JLabel right, down, up, left, chat;
    JTextField chatmessage;
    ImageIcon im, im2, im3, im4;
    int keys = 0, size = 600, playerWidth = 10, playerHeight = 20, speed = 6, cycletime, g, e, tempe, chatvar = 0;
    int x = (size / 2) - (playerWidth / 2);
    int y = (size / 2) - (playerHeight / 2);

    gametest() {
        f1 = new JFrame("Game");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        im = new ImageIcon("right.png");
        im2 = new ImageIcon("down.png");
        im3 = new ImageIcon("up.png");
        im4 = new ImageIcon("left.png");
        right = new JLabel(im);
        down = new JLabel(im2);
        up = new JLabel(im3);
        left = new JLabel(im4);
        chat = new JLabel("   ");
        chatmessage = new JTextField();

        p1.setLayout(null);

        f1.add(p1);
        p1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("DayBackground.png")));
        p1.add(right);
        p1.add(down);
        p1.add(up);
        p1.add(left);
        p1.add(chat);
        p1.add(chatmessage);

        right.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        down.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        up.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        left.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        chat.setBounds(50, (size - 150), 100, 25);
        chatmessage.setBounds(50, (size - 100), 100, 25);

        f1.setSize(size, size);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        p1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setResizable(false);

        right.setVisible(false);
        down.setVisible(true);
        up.setVisible(false);
        left.setVisible(false);
        chat.setVisible(false);
        chatmessage.setVisible(false);
        f1.setFocusable(true);
        p1.setBackground(new Color(113, 204, 0));//Green and Day
        g = 1;
        cycletime = 6000;
        f1.addKeyListener(this);

        for (int j = 0;;j++) {
            for (e = 0;e <= cycletime;e++) {
                System.out.println(e);
                f1.setFocusable(true);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    System.out.println(ie);
                }
            }
            f1.addKeyListener(this);
            if (g == 1) {//Night
                p1.setBackground(new Color(1, 50, 32));//Gray
                g = 0;
                cycletime = 9000;
            }
            else if (g == 0) {//Day
                p1.setBackground(new Color(113, 204, 0));//Green
                g = 1;
                cycletime = 6000;
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        keys = keys + 1;

        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && keys == 1 || ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W && keys == 1) {
            y = y - speed;
            right.setVisible(false);
            down.setVisible(false);
            up.setVisible(true);
            left.setVisible(false);
            up.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                System.out.println("Up-Arrow-Key Pressed.");
            }
            else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                System.out.println("W-Key Pressed.");
            }
            System.out.println("X-Position: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y-Position: " + y);
            System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
            System.out.println("Size: " + size);
            System.out.println("playerWidth: " + playerWidth);
            System.out.println("playerHeight: " + playerHeight);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && keys == 1 || ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && keys == 1) {
            y = y + speed;
            right.setVisible(false);
            down.setVisible(true);
            up.setVisible(false);
            left.setVisible(false);
            down.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("Down-Arrow-Key Pressed.");
            }
            else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                System.out.println("S-Key Pressed.");
            }
            System.out.println("X-Position: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y-Position: " + y);
            System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
            System.out.println("Size: " + size);
            System.out.println("playerWidth: " + playerWidth);
            System.out.println("playerHeight: " + playerHeight);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && keys == 1 || ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && keys == 1) {
            x = x - speed;
            right.setVisible(false);
            down.setVisible(false);
            up.setVisible(false);
            left.setVisible(true);
            left.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("Left-Arrow-Key Pressed.");
            }
            else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                System.out.println("A-Key Pressed.");
            }
            System.out.println("X-Position: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y-Position: " + y);
            System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
            System.out.println("Size: " + size);
            System.out.println("playerWidth: " + playerWidth);
            System.out.println("playerHeight: " + playerHeight);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && keys == 1 || ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D && keys == 1) {
            x = x + speed;
            right.setVisible(true);
            down.setVisible(false);
            up.setVisible(false);
            left.setVisible(false);
            right.setBounds(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                System.out.println("Right-Arrow-Key Pressed.");
            }
            else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                System.out.println("D-Key Pressed.");
            }
            System.out.println("X-Position: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y-Position: " + y);
            System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
            System.out.println("Size: " + size);
            System.out.println("playerWidth: " + playerWidth);
            System.out.println("playerHeight: " + playerHeight);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C && keys == 1) {
            if (chatvar == 1) {
                chatmessage.setVisible(false);
                chatvar = 0;
            }
            else {
                chatmessage.setVisible(true);
                chatvar = 1;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                chatmessage.setVisible(false);
                chatvar = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && keys == 1 && chatvar == 1) {
            String str2 = chatmessage.getText();
            chat.setText(str2);
            chat.setVisible(true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            chat.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_N && keys == 1) {//Turn it night.
            if (g != 0) {
                e = cycletime;
                g = 1;
            }
            else {
                //nothing...
            }
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M && keys == 1) {//Turn it daytime.
            if (g != 1) {
                e = cycletime;
                g = 0;
            }
            else {
                //nothing...
            }
        }
        else {
            if ((keys - 1) > -1) {
                keys = keys - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keys = 0;
        System.out.println("Keys:" + keys);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            //Blank...
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        gametest obj = new gametest();
    }
}
```

By the way sorry for the and here text coming inside the codes:D.

Comment: What do you mean with 'opening' or 'connecting' projects? Do you mean in your IDE?

Comment: Tip: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions; class names always start with uppercase, i.e. `gameteststart` should be `Gameteststart` et cetera. Second, this is very much code, you should strip the code down the parts relevant to the question. It'll be easier to help you.

Comment: MC Emperor thanks for advice i will keep in mind. Actually, i am new here :D.

Comment: Also Wesley by connecting i mean that when i press a button on one project's Frame and Panel it should open up the other's Frame and Panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want classes to be used in other projects and if you are using an IDE like IntelliJ, Netbeans or Eclipse then you will need to add the project as a Library or Dependency. Normally this is under "Project Structure" or "Project Settings".

Other ways you can do it is to have different modules under the same project.

If you are not using an IDE then you'll need to compile the project and include the .class files or ideally .jar file in your build.

Comment: Thanks actually i am just using notepad and compiling with notepad. I haven't thought of using a IDE yet. So i just want to solve it without having to do any file insertion/deletion type of work just by coding. Is there any flaw in my code. Please tell i am struggling on this topic since long and want to solve this now.

Comment: On the whole looks ok my initial comments would be: class names by convention start with a capital letter and the first letter of every word in it is a capital e.g. GameStartTest and Game test. You also have a redunant line f1.addKeyListener(this); in the for loop in gametest constructor and I wonder if the for loops is the best iteration statement here, maybe a while statement might reader better.

Comment: Also you say you have two different "Projects" do you mean projects or class files? Because there is a difference

Comment: Actually yeah you can say class files. Shall i try to change those class names will it work? Also actually the for loop is for Day-Night Cycle of the Game But there's a problem with that also. When i press a key it is supposed to move the player but from the time i have added that for loop the player isn't moving on pressing the key. But it still works if we press the key just at the start of the loop. =>

Comment: <= That means there's some problem with the loop that is causing the key thing not to work. So, I was just trying to fix that problem while i searched for an answer to my first problem. I haven't just asked it here but to some of my friends also. But i guess right now it's one of the least of our worries.

Comment: Richard Stokes Thanks for helping me out. It's really awesome to know someone is there to help me out on this :D. Also actually i tried making a jar file but it is not working with me for some reason. I am not able to make one jar file

Comment: It was the for loop and key listener problem that made me use the line f1.addKeyListener(this); Also if u have a better solution for my other problem also please tell. If while loop will be able to help in this case that will be great kindly send me the code. Though, i was planning on posting this as a separate topic completely but it will be a really great help if u would be able to solve this problem also.